# How to create a modal for a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make an extension for VSCode to Find text in File (Like in Notepad++).

Is there an API for using a modal in a VSCode extension? or at least extend the Command Palette?

Comment: You should check out the API docs. There you find everything regarding [registering commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands) as well as showing [modal messages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#MessageOptions)

Comment: Nothing in the API about modals.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code (1.34) has no concept modal UI. Extensions can only show basic dialog messages modally using the [showMessage](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInformationMessage) apis.

Messages can show message text and a set of buttons. By default VS Code will render messages in its UI. The  [`MessageOptions.modal`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#MessageOptions) option makes VS Code render the message using system UI instead.

---

Try positing a more specific question about what you are trying to accomplish. VS Code's extension model is different from other editors, so if you are trying to replicate functionality from another editor like Notepad++ you may need to rethink the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is an [input box](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox). It will show a UI where you can input text. From there you can grab the text of a document and parse it for entered text. For completeness, VS Code does this with `ctrl + f` or `cmd + f` depending on OS. Add the `shift` key to search the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above there are the limited built-in inputs and message box (which can also be used to display choice buttons).

You can also have a look at WebView these can be used to display a side-bar view (like the EXPLORER) or a full document. They are made up from HTML and plain old JavaScript. You will have to pass simple string messages between your HTML/JS view and vscode itself.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample

A large 'document' view example vscode extension is call 'nearest-icons'
https://github.com/noGreg/nearest-icons